Where does docker store configuration of permanent containers?
If I start a container with --restart=always, it gets restarted after a reboot. Where is the configuration telling the docker daemon to start a specific container and its arguments and restart policy stored?

How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container? talks about editing these files; is the answer to your question there?  The most correct answer is "in Docker-internal storage you really shouldn't be directly accessing", though.

Yep perfect, thank you! If you'd like to submit this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as solved.
